# the maximum number of pairs of K5 subgraphs in an n-planarizable graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am having a question in an Assignment at my college:
How can i find the maximum number of pairs of node-disjoint-copies of 5-complete (sub-) graphes (K5) which are included in an 5-planarisable graph G ?

Hint: k-planarisable graphs is when we have S a subset of V (Vertexes Set of Graph G) where |S| = k and V - S = planar Graph
I was trying to find out how many K5 in G through counting the number of the edges which the K5 should have AND the number of Edges for the G knowing that it is 5-planar (with at least 10 nodes to be able to have at least one pair of node-disjoint-copies of K5 knowing that the planar graph has maximally 3n-6 Edges (Euler theorem) where n is the number of nodes ).
The solution should be done in using the Combinatoric formula, but i could't come along to a result.

Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: Right now the top Google result for "n-planarizable graph", at least for me, is this question, so it might help if you define this term... Plus, as always, you should include your own thoughts and efforts.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Let $n$ be the number of vertices of $G$. Since the copies are node-disjoint, there are at most $\lfloor n/5\rfloor$ of them. On the other hand, it is easy to check that $K_5$ is $1$-planar, so a union of $\lfloor n/5\rfloor$ node-disjoint copies of $K_5$ is $1$-planar graph, that shows that this bound is tight.